# C++ composite function call and evaluation

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to call function from another function. I am creating 2 vectors in `main()` abd passing them to `fun2()`. `fun2` calls `fun1` with parameters as `(4.0 -2.0*p, 5.0+3.0*p)`. `fun1` should return `5*(4.0 -2.0*p)^2 + 4*(5.0+3.0*p)^2 + 14`. This will result in function with `p` as parameter which will be evaluated by line `//Question` : value `3` should be put there. But the syntax or method is not quite right. How can I evaluate composite functions like this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

double fun1(double x1, double x2)
{
    double res1 = std::pow(x1,2.0)*5.0 + std::pow(x2,2)*4.0 + 14.0; 
    return res1;
}

double fun2(const std::vector<double> *v1, const std::vector<double> *v2, double(*f1)(double, double))
{
    double p, res2;
    res2 = fun1(((*v1)[0] + p*(*v2)[0]), ((*v1)[1] + p*(*v2)[1]) );
    return res2;
}

int main()
{
    double res3;
    std::vector<double> v1 = { 4.0,5.0 };
    std::vector<double> v2 = { -2.0,3.0 };
    res3 = fun2(&v1, &v2, &fun1)(3); //Question

    return 0;
}
```

Update:

I am trying to evaluate function like `fun2(fun1(3))`, which is possible in languages like python.

Comment: What do you mean by "he syntax or method is not quite right"? The first thing would be to replace pointers with references `const std::vector<double> & v1`. Also you are using `p` while it is not initialized. And there is no need to name variables like `res1` `res2` `res3` because they live in different scopes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want maintain the call syntax

```
res3 = fun2(&v1, &v2, &fun1)(3);
```

I suggest the use of a lambda function; something like

```
auto fun2 (const std::vector<double> *v1,
           const std::vector<double> *v2,
           double(*f1)(double, double))
   -> std::function<double(double)>
{
    return [&](double p)
     { return fun1(((*v1)[0] + p*(*v2)[0]), ((*v1)[1] + p*(*v2)[1])); };
}
```

Starting from C++14 you can avoid the use of the `std::function` type and (simply using `auto` as return type) directly return the lambda function

```
auto fun2 (const std::vector<double> *v1,
           const std::vector<double> *v2,
           double(*f1)(double, double))
{
    return [&](double p)
     { return fun1(((*v1)[0] + p*(*v2)[0]), ((*v1)[1] + p*(*v2)[1])); };
}
```

Off Topic: taking in count that you don't modify the vector, I suggest to pass they as const references; so

```
auto fun2 (std::vector<double> const& v1,
           std::vector<double> const& v2,
           double(*f1)(double, double))
{
    return [&](double p)
     { return fun1(v1[0] + p*v2[0], v1[1] + p*v2[1]); };
}
```

called as

```
res3 = fun2(v1, v2, fun1)(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to to implement a higher-order function, so `fun2()` is supposed to return a lambda that captures all the parameters, then use:

```
std::function<double(double)> fun2(const std::vector<double> *v1, const std::vector<double> *v2, double(*f1)(double, double))
{
    // Return a std::function that can accept parameter p as
    // argument and call f1 with v1, v2, and p.
    return [v1, v2, f1](double p) -> double
    {
       return f1(((*v1)[0] + p*(*v2)[0]), ((*v1)[1] + p*(*v2)[1]) );
    };
}
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/WhFwXU.

Comment: It should also be `f1(((`

Comment: I think he's trying to implement a higher-order function, so `fun2()` is supposed to return a lambda that captures all the parameters.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, of course.

Comment: That's why he's using `(3)` in `main()`, rather than making it an argument to `fun2`.

Comment: Updated question. I am not trying to pass value to `fun2()`

Comment: @Barmar, I think you are right.

Comment: @udmw233, see the updated answer.